# `git checkout source_branch <paths>` and specify the file on the current branch?

Tags: git

I have been trying to grab a file from an alternate git branch and copy the file onto the current branch under a new specified name.

I have found how to copy the a file from an alternate branch on to the current branch utilizing `git checkout source_branch <paths>` as specified [here](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) but I have been unable to identify how to specify a new file name?

Comment: The way I do it is `git show` on the file from the other branch and redirect the input to a new file on the current branch. Not an efficient approach for many files, though.

Comment: Definitely useful though! and a creative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to use the command `git show commitish:path > newpath`.  The `commitish` here can be a branch name as usual.